# How to get all atrributes of a class/instance?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inspect python class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241171/inspect-python-class-attributes)

I need to get a clean list of the names of all attributes defined my me in a class. Lets say I have the next class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    attr1 = None
    attr2 = 2
    attr3 = "Hello world"
```

I would like to know if there is something that allows me to do:

```
>>> some_method(MyClass)  # <- check class
['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
>>> my_class = MyClass()
>>> some_method(my_class)  # <- check instance of MyClass
['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
```

I can't rely on the built-in method `dir` since it also returns attributes like `__class__`, `__getattr__` and any method the class has. I mean, I need to get **ONLY** the attributes defined in the class, not the built-in ones too, neither the methods.

Is that even possible? or is there any way to know what attributes are built-in and which ones are defined by me so that I can loop over the list `dir` returns and make some `filter`ing?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module to do this.

Here's an example:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> filter(lambda x: not (x.startswith('__') and x.endswith('__')), [a for (a, b) in inspect.getmembers(MyClass, lambda x : (not inspect.ismethod(x) and not inspect.isbuiltin(x)) )])
['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
```

The basic idea is to run `inspect.getmembers` to get all the members of some object. This supports both objects as well as classes. Methods and builtins are filtered using the predicate lambda expression supplied as optional argument to `inspect.getmembers`. Then, list comprehension is used to get just the names of each of the members, and lastly `__dict__` etc is filtered out using the Python filter function.

The filtering for `__dict__` etc is not very "scientific", but I think it should do for most cases :)

Comment: Don't like too much the `startswith` and `endwith` part, but it solves my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a starting point:

```
>>> [x for x in dir(a) if not x in dir(super(type(a)))]
['__dict__', '__module__', '__weakref__', 'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3']
```

Returns everything in an object's `dir` that isn't from its parent class' `dir`.

One thing it does well is filter out the methods defined in the class, but not touch instance attributes which happen to be functions.

Comment: List comprehensions. My preferred method too.

Comment: But this only works on instances, not on classes.

Comment: Oh, and if anything re-defined something defined on the class it won't be listed either.

Comment: Good aproach, unfortunately for me `__dict__`, `__module__`, `__weakref__` hinders me for my purpose. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Functions are *also* attributes, there is nothing stopping you from assigning additional functions to a class or an instance at a later time. So you are asking if you can list all attributes that are *not* functions, and not 'special'.

If you want to list anything that is defined *directly* on the class or instance, look at the `.__dict__` mapping instead.  You'll still have to filter that:

```
import types

def objectAttributes(obj):
    for key, val in obj.__dict__.iteritems():
        if not isinstance(val, (types.FunctionType, types.MethodType)):
            yield key
```

This'll generate all attribute names that are not functions or methods, which should work both for classes and for instances that had methods assigned to them manually.

To get a list as output, call `list(objectAttributes(MyClass))` or `list(objectAttributes(myinstance))`.

This method does *not* traverse base classes, and will fall down if you use [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) on your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
t = MyClass()
result = []
for k,v in t.__dict__.items(): #all members of MyClass
    if not hasattr(v, '__call__'):#if it's not  a callable 
        result.append(k)
```